# Making around 20 HTTP calls and passing data to the database using Java

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java

I have a collection of 20 items, I will create a loop for the items and make API Calls to get the data, based on the data returned, I will have to update in the database. This requirement is simple and I am able to accomplish in plain Java.

Now for performance, I am learning about using `RxJava`. I went through many articles in the internet and found that people refer to the `async-http-client` library for async http calls, I find that the library is out of date and the maintainer is planning for a hand-over to someone else, the one given in RxJava library is also like developed in 2014. Since I am new to RxJava, can you please help me with the right approach.

I am currently getting all the data and converting to observables like below

```
Observable<ENV> envs= Observable.fromIterable(allEnvs);
```

I also need to get some help like is the above code fine or should I create like the following for the observable construction, this is the snippet in groovy which I will have to write in Java.

```
val createObserver = Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<String> { emitter ->
    emitter.onNext("Hello World")
    emitter.onComplete()
})
```

Kindly help me in choosing the best approach

Comment: sorry the question is not clear

Comment: I need to make 20 API calls and wanted to do this in parallel to reduce latency and probably using `CompletableFuture`

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the http call is represented by class below :

```java
public class HttpCall implements Callable<String> {

    private final int i;

    private HttpCall(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Something for : " + i;
    }
}
```

It waits 2 sec and then emits a string (the http call result).

To combine all the items resulting from different http calls we can use `merge` operator. But before that we need to transform the `Callable` to an `Observable` by using `fromCallable` operator.

```java
void sequentially() {
    List<Observable<String>> httpRequests = IntStream.range(0, 20)
            .mapToObj(HttpCall::new)
            .map(Observable::fromCallable)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Observable.merge(httpRequests)
            .timestamp(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(e -> System.out.println("Elapsed time : " + e.time() + " -- " + e.value() + ". Executed on thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
}
```

Because all the requests are executed on the same thread, the order is maintained :

> Elapsed time : 1602122218 -- Something for : 0. Executed on thread : main
> Elapsed time : 1602122220 -- Something for : 1. Executed on thread : main
> Elapsed time : 1602122222 -- Something for : 2. Executed on thread : main
> ...

As you can see the items are separated by 2 sec.

To run each request in its own thread we need to tell Rx that we need a thread for each call. Easy-peasy, just switch to one of the suggested schedulers. IO its what we need (as it's an IO operation).

```java
void parallel( {
    List<Observable<String>> httpRequests = IntStream.range(0, 20)
            .mapToObj(HttpCall::new)
            .map(httpCall -> Observable.fromCallable(httpCall)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ) // take a thread from the IO pool
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Observable.merge(httpRequests)
            .timestamp(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(e -> System.out.println("Elapsed time : " + e.time() + " -- " + e.value() + ". Executed on thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
}
```

This time the order is not guarenteed and they are produced at almost the same time :

> Elapsed time : 1602123707 -- Something for : 2. Executed on thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
> Elapsed time : 1602123707 -- Something for : 0. Executed on thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
> Elapsed time : 1602123707 -- Something for : 1. Executed on thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
> ...

---

The code could be shorten like :

```java
Observable.range(0, 20)
                .map(HttpCall::new)
                .flatMap(httpCall -> Observable.fromCallable(httpCall).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                .timestamp(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribe(e -> System.out.println("Elapsed time : " + e.time() + " -- " + e.value() + ". Executed on thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

`merge` uses `flatMap` behind scenes.