# How to call multiple Flowable statements in parallel?

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a few function calls that return Flowable object. I have to call this function multiple times and this function is doing some network calls. I want to do all these calls concurrently.
Below is the code.

**Interface containing the function**

```
public Interface XYZDownstreamService {

  Flowable<String> getData(Request request);
}
```

**Below is the Caller**

```
public List<String> getDataFromDownstreamForRequests(List<Request> requests, XYZDownstreamService service) {
    List<String> dataFromDownstream = Lists.newArrayList();
    for(Request request: requests) {
        dataFromDownstream.add(service.getData(request).blockingFirst());
    }
    return dataFromDownstream;
}
```

I want to do the above function calls concurrently to optimize the for a loop. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: do you mean Flowable - business process engine or io.reactivex.Flowable - interface from RxJava?

Comment: yes it's from RxJava

Answer (score 2):

You just need to merge your requests using `merge` or `flatMap`. Moreover, use a diffrent threads to process your requests using `observeOn`.

```java
Flowable.merge(requests
  .stream()
  .map(r -> service.getData(r)
              .observeOn(Schedulers.io())))
  .collect(toList())
).subscribe()
```

Or write it like :

```java
Flowable.fromIterable(requests)
        .flatMap(r -> service.getData(r)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io()))
        .subscribe();
```

I've already reply to a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64254923/8325761) question for more details.